# $f: \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R} $ is strictly increasing

Tags: analysis

While I'm well aware of what "strictly increasing" means for a function that maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, I'm unclear about what is meant by

$f: \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R} $ is strictly increasing

Does it mean that

$$ x >> y \implies f(x) > f(y) $$

OR does it mean that

$$ x \ge y, x \neq y \implies f(x) > f(y) $$

where $x >> y \Leftrightarrow x_i > y_i\ \forall i=1,2,\ldots, n$ and $ x\ge y \Leftrightarrow x_i \ge y_i\ \forall i=1,2,\ldots,n$.

Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Perhaps $x\ge y$ means $x_i\ge y_i$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$?

Comment: Could you provide context?

Comment: You need first to provide an order in $\mathbb R^n$, otherwise the term “strictly increasing” is meaningless.  There is no natural complete order in $\mathbb R^n$, but @lhf 's partial order might be appropriate when lacking any further context.

Comment: @lhf, indeed, that's what meant. Added it for clarification. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not standard terminology and either of your definitions might be reasonable in the right context. I might also interpret it to mean that $f$ has no local maxima, i.e. that for every neighborhood $V$ of a point $p\in \mathbb{R}^n$, there exists a $q\in V$ with $f(q) > f(p)$.

Comment: Agreed.  Any book or paper that uses this language should first provide a definition to be used.